# Do I use well present perfect in that case

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect

> 1. **I already made** an order, **so I've paid** 2 times shipping, would you mind refunding me for the second shipping and send both orders together?

Would it be better to write

> 2. **I've already made** an order, **so I've paid** 2 times shipping, would you mind refunding me for the second shipping and send both orders together?
> 3. **I already made** an order, **so I paid** 2 times shipping, would you mind refunding me for the second shipping and send both orders together?

I think the first one is better because when I am writing  this I have just finished the second order and if I am asking some refund now it is because of the second order.

Comment: If you're asking only about tenses, I would pick the second one.

Comment: In the meantime, I know that English is not your first language, so I think the sentences are fine as-is (and for better or worse, would let customer support know that there may be language barriers), but one "mistake" I would recommend you definitely change is to say, "so I've paid for shipping twice."